# Outliner and Layer

Tags: modeling

In Blender the "outliner" Panel displays an overview of all objects in the current project. During work I moved a Blueprint to an other Layer, but if i want to bring it back to Layer 1 i realized that the "outliner" dont show the current layer of an object. After a Hour i found out that the layer displayed in the the "Properties" panel under "Object" > "Relations" > "Layers". Is there an faster way to find out the current Layer? Or is there an Addone to Show the Layer of an Object in the outliner Panel (where it belongs i suggest)?

Answer (score 1):

**The layers of a scene are here:** At the bottom of the 3D view window
There are 20 of them and they are accessible when in Object Mode.

[image]

A selected object will show the layer where is at with a bright orange dot (The dot will show even if the layer is the active layer in the viewport)

[image]

If the object is active in multiple layers then you'll see a bright orange dot for every layer in which the object is active.

[image]

There are two ways to make an object be in a layer.

**1-** Select the object you want to move and press **<kbd>M</kbd>** and select the layer you want to move to:

[image]

Or you can just type **<kbd>M</kbd>** and the layer number. 
E.G. <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> will move the object to layer 4

To have the object exist in more than one layer press the <kbd>Shift</kbd>key  while selecting. For example <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> will make the object exist in layers 1,3 and 4.
This image reflects that:

[image]

**To make layers visible** Just enable them at the bottom of the 3D View window  by clicking on them. To enable more than one layer use shift.

[image]

2- The other way to determine an object belong to a layer is on the **properties window** Relations section:

[image]

Comment: ah thanks, i dont realize that the same Object can exist  across multiple levels(layers). Make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no faster way to do it and no add-on that can display them in the outliner. The object can be on multiple layers, so you would need a space for these 20 layers in outliner.